# Flutter: Retrieve data based on List of Values from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, yield

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with code. The list contains two items but the function only return the first and after a second the first one disappeared:

```
Stream<List<Forum>> getListOfOwnerCourses() async* {
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    final snap = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(firebaseUser.uid).get();
    List<Forum> _courseList = [];
    List myOwnCourses = [];
    if (snap.exists && snap.data['myOwnCourses'] != null) {
      myOwnCourses = snap.data['myOwnCourses'];
      for (String co in myOwnCourses) {
        print("$co Dler");
        var courses = await Firestore.instance.collection('courses').document(co).get();
        Forum forum = Forum.fromSnapshot(courses);
        _courseList.add(forum);
        yield _courseList;
      }
    }
    print("${_courseList[1].title}");
  }
```